# Python3 compatability with file object

Tags: python, file, io, backwards-compatibility

I have a class/object that is a subprocess of a bunch of cmds in linux.  The object has something like:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, bufsize=-1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")
    return self.process.stdout
```

This basically return a `file` object in Python2 and an `_io.BufferedReader` for Python3.

I perform a bunch of logic on each line and create a bunch of generators.  What is the best way to support both python 2 and 3.  For example if I have something like

```
line = input_file.next().strip().split(' ')
```

Works okay with Python 2, but for Python 3 I'll get something like

```
`_io.BufferedReader` object has no attribute 'next'
```

If I update `input_file.next()` to be `input_file.readline()` I would get an error of:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I can keep updating it accordingly to work for Python3, but is there a better way to do it without completely different algo/logic per each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level built-in function `next` works on both Python 2 and Python 3, so instead of `input_file.next()` use `next(input_file)`. As for consistently splitting on ASCII space characters, just put a `b` prefix on the string you're using to split; it changes nothing on Python 2 (`b' '` is identical to `' '`, both being `str` on Python 2), and on Python 3, it makes it a `bytes` object (which binary mode `Popen` processes produce).

Final version of code is:

```
line = next(input_file).strip().split(b' ')
```

and works identically on both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply here.  My issue was actually way before I got to this code, but this definitely helped, thanks!